# How can convert Xml code to linq

Tags: xml, linq

I am fallowing a tutorial And it works great.But I am wondering How can i do this with linq

I am trying something like this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=" + lang+ "&output=toolbar&q=" + word+ "");

var suggestions = doc.Descandands("suggestions").Where( ....
```

But I am  confused a little bit.This is my xml code

```
string lang = drpLang.SelectedValue;
    //TextBoxa girilen değer alınır.
    string word = txtSearch.Text;
    //Google Suggest Değelerini içeren Labelı ilk başta temizliyoruz.
    lblRetVal.Text = "";
    /*Burada Google Suggest değerlerini içeren servisin kaynak kodunu alıyoruz.
     * Xml olarak çekerken eşleşmeyen karakterler olduğu için böyle bir yol izliyoruz.
     * */
    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=" + dil + "&output=toolbar&q=" + kelime + "");
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader retValues = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string html = retValues.ReadToEnd();

    //XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    ////Tüm sayfayı çektiğimiz için sayfanın kaynak kodunu xml olarak yüklenmesi sağlıyoruz.
    //xdoc.LoadXml(html);
    //XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("toplevel/CompleteSuggestion/suggestion");
    ////Burada alınan nodeları döngüye alıyoruz.
    //foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
    //{
    //    //Alınan nodeların data Attributes değerini tek tek labela yazdırıyoruz.
    //    lblRetVal.Text += item.Attributes["data"].InnerText + "<br>";
    //}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you would query xml data by using linq, I suggest you to create a class contains all xml elements in selected descendant and consider my sample code below.

First I create class containing all xml elements I want to query

```
public class CompleteSuggestion
{
    public string suggestionData { get; set;}
}
```

And this my linq to xml

```
public List<CompleteSuggestion> GetSuggestions(string lang, string word) 
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=" + lang+ "&output=toolbar&q=" + word+ "");
    List<CompleteSuggestion> suggestions = (from s in doc.Descendants("suggestion")
                                            select new CompleteSuggestion
                                            {
                                                suggestionData = s.Attribute("data").Value
                                            }).ToList();
    return suggestions;
}
```

Final, call the method where you want and use it

```
List<CompleteSuggestion> suggestions = GetSuggestions("en", "angle");
foreach (CompleteSuggestion s in suggestions)
{
    Response.Write(s.suggestionData);
}
```